# How to force ProGuard to remove public static method?

Tags: java, proguard

I have multiple classes in my application that provide `public static void main(String[] args)` methods. These methods are only required during development / testing, and I'd like ProGuard to remove them (but only these methods, not the entire surrounding classes). I've tried to use `-assumenosideeffects`, but that only seems to affect calls to methods, not the methods themselves. How can I force Proguard to remove the entire `main()` methods despite them being `public` and `static`?

Comment: isn't there an optimization that removes unused methods already?

Comment: Sure there is, if you enable shrinking unused code gets removed. But the point is that you cannot tell for sure whether a `public static` method is unused, because it might be used from outside of your code. That's why I need to force the removal somehow.

Comment: i think that what proguard gives you is the ability to exclude functions and classes from being modified by it, so can't you use it on the functions that you wish it won't touch?

Comment: Indeed ProGuard has several `-keep` options, but I don't want to keep anything that ProGuard would remove otherwise. I want the opposite, force something to be removed that ProGuard keeps by default.

Comment: yes, so maybe you can have the optimization of removing everything that isn't being used , and you set which things to keep. isn't it logically the same?

Comment: Well, first of all, using the "inverse" logic and adding rules for everything to remove (instead of just the thing to keep) would be a lot of work (and that's exactly what ProGuard is supposed to find out by itself), and secondly there simply seem to be no way to explicitly tell ProGuard which methods to remove. You can only specific explicitly which methods to keep. That's the whole point of my question ...

Comment: but logically it's the same. you just tell it which to keep. usually you would like to remove all except for a few that you wish to keep. maybe you could put all of those that you wish to keep inside a class that is protected from proguard, and you get what you want?

Comment: No, sorry, your suggestions just won't work for me.

Comment: they can't work, or they don't fit to your needs?

Comment: They can't work. Just telling ProGuard what to keep won't make it automatically remove the rest. ProGuard has its own logic of determining what code is used and what not, and you cannot override it that way.

Answer (score 1):

ProGuard needs seeds to determine which classes/methods need to be kept. Anything referenced from these seeds will also be kept.

The `-assumenosideeffects` option is used to remove actual calls to methods whose result is not used in any way, but does not necessarily mean that the method itself is removed.

In your specific case, you probably have a rule that keeps all `public static void main(String[])` methods as this would be the standard seed for a java application.

You can analyse the reason why a specific method/class is kept using the `-whyareyoukeeping` option.